# Toggle icon on primeNg tree without children | Angular 8

Tags: angular, primeng

In p-tree toggle icon is visible only if tree has a children. I need to show it by my own property `in data: haschildre`. My tree`s json Components

```
{
    label: 'Documents',
    data: [{ id: 1, name: 'MyDocument', type: 'Document', loading: false, hasChildren: true }],
    children: []
  },
  {
    label: 'Documents',
    data: [{ id: 1, name: 'MyDocument', type: 'Document', loading: false }],
    children: [
      { label: 'MyDocument', icon: 'fa fa-file-image-o',
      data: [{ id: 1, name: 'MyDocument', type: 'Document', loading: false, hasChildren: false }] },
      {
        label: 'MyCollection', icon: 'fa fa-file-image-o',
      data: [{ id: 1, name: 'MyCollection', type: 'Collection', loading: false, hasChildren: false  }]
      },
      { label: 'MyWork', icon: 'fa fa-file-image-o',
      data: [{ id: 1, name: 'MyWork', type: 'Pictures', loading: false, hasChildren: false  }] }]
  },
```

My tree HTML

```
<p-tree  (onNodeExpand)="loadNode($event)" styleClass="prime-css" [value]="files">
<ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">

        <span *ngIf="node.data[0].type === 'Document'">&#x000AE; </span>
        <span *ngIf="node.data[0].type === 'Collection'">&#x00023; </span>
        <span *ngIf="node.data[0].type === 'Work'">&#x000A7; </span>
        <span *ngIf="node.data[0].type === 'Pictures'">&#x000A7; </span>

        <span [class]="node.data[0].type" style="margin-left: 5px;">{{node.label}}</span>
        <p-progressSpinner *ngIf="node.data[0].loading === true" [style]="{width: '20x', height: '20px'}"
            strokeWidth="2"></p-progressSpinner>
</ng-template>
```

it has such view on HTML

[image]

How I can do it?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of your issue ?

Comment: No I can only show HTML code and and view in screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Set the leaf value as false and toggle icon will appear.

Example:

```
{
    label: 'Demo',
    data: [],
    children: [],
    leaf:false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible through typescript as well

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
      for (let i = 0; i <= (document.getElementsByTagName('p-treetabletoggler').length); i++) {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('p-treetabletoggler')[i] !== undefined) {
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
        (document.getElementsByTagName('p-treetabletoggler')[i].firstElementChild as HTMLElement).style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
    }
  }
```